# Software updater warning: requires installation of untrusted packages

Tags: updates, update-manager

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and when I try update for Software updater I always get this error:

[image]

I also tried to not download some packages and download the main ones but the error always stays there.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is some problem in yout cache run those commands to solve it:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /var/lib/apt/lists.bak
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
```

[source and more info](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1983220)

Comment: I can confirm this works!  Why doesn't @Maythux have more up-votes? :) After running the final `apt-get update`, I re-opened the Software Updater and proceeded normally.

Comment: Worked beautifully in my Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks a ton @Maythux..

Comment: I still get the same error

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem. This happens due to the missing of some GPG keys.

Go to **applications->accessories->terminal** or press **CTRL+ALT+T**.

And, type below commands:-

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

You will get an error saying that some public key is not available. Note the key string ( after the NO_PUBKEY; eg:3C962022012520A0 )

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com XXXXXX
```

Replace the XXXXXX with the key string

Ex:- `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3C962022012520A0`

Now try updating your system again.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This will surely solve this issue.

Comment: After executing `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` I had an error messages *GPG error: http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian testing InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available*. Adding public key for rabbitmq repo fixed the issue.

Comment: @jekis have you try another method mentioned in my answer ?

Comment: I just wanted to say that your suggestion pointed me to the real problem on my computer. And the whole update issue has been resolved after adding the rabbitmq public key.

Comment: @Jekis if your issue is fixed by this method, i think then it needs one upvote. This will help other persons, in getting the right answer to solve this issue.